# can i use a c++ static library compiled with xcode in android studio?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, static-libraries, objective-c++

i have some questions regarding static library of c++ files and xcode and android studio (probably is the same with eclipse):

- can i use a c++ static library compiled with xcode (.a) in android
  studio (using ndk)?
- also, what if the static library contains some cpp and also .mm
  objective c code?
- if not, can i build the .a (of the cpp files) in android studio?

i would appreciate any leads on the subject. 
thanks allot!

Comment: Hey there, I like your idea and I am working on a similar task! Since there's some time gone: Did you make any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) No.

(b) No.

(c) Not at the moment.

(d) Use the Android NDK (Android Native Development Kit) http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: but i want to build a static library before using it in an app with the NDK. how would i do that so that it is compatible with android?

Comment: The majority of Android devices are ARM based, so you need a cross compiler.  The Android NDK includes instructions for setting up a cross compiler for existing projects.  Or you can just drop your existing source code into an Android-NDK project.

Comment: Section you may want to read is "Standalone Toolchain" in the NDK docs

Answer (score 0):

You could, if you can accept using an External Build System target which runs `ndk-build`. You will have to provide the `.mk` files for `ndk-build`, but that's not much of an issue.